# reverse chunk split of integer in PHP

Tags: php, split

I need split by gap like when we write count numbers we will give gap for every 3 integer.

```
echo chunk_split(1000255869,3," ");
```

I got output like: `100 025 586 9`

But I need output like: `1,000,255,869`

How to reverse that one?

Comment: I think you are looking for number formatting if that is the case then use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: try this echo wordwrap(1000255869,3," ,", true )

Comment: Ya right . ButI need to give space instead of coma

Comment: leave third parameter as empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do a number format, you should do it with number_format.

```
echo number_format(1000255869,0,".",",");
```

Comment: `number_format('+1234567', 0, '', ' ');` would add spaces - however notice it is NUMBER format => the plus (or other non-number characters would be removed) so this is really only usable for "pure" number

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php

$a = 1000255869;
echo $a;//output - 1000255869
$a = number_format($a);
echo $a;//output - 1,000,255,869

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work `number_format(1000255869, 0, '.', ',');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
   $number= 1000255869;
   echo number_format($number);
```